# AngularJS - Using variable name in JSON selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have a table using angularjs where I want to loop through an array to print specific headers from a json object. The header prints out fine, but the problem comes when I try to use a variable from my nested ng-repeat as a json selector. If you replace the inner ng-repeat with the commented section below it, it will work.

Table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th ng-repeat="column in tableHeader">{{column}}&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by(column);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></i></a></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered>
            <td ng-repeat="column2 in tableHeader">{{data.column2}}</td>
<!-- <td>{{data.Environment}}</td>
    <td>{{data.HostIP}}</td>
    <td>{{data.ServiceName}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Status}}</td>
    <td>{{data.StartTime}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Capacity}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Txn}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Errors}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Build}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Project}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Author}}</td>
    <td>{{data.ModifyDate}}</td>
    <td>{{data.Port}}</td>
    <td>{{data.BasePath}}</td> -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Array located in controller:

```
$scope.tableHeader = ['Environment', 'HostIP', 'Status', 'ServiceName', 'StartTime', 'Capacity', 'Txn', 'Errors', 'Build', 'Project', 'Author', 'ModifyDate', 'Port', 'BasePath'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `{{data[column2]}}`. Since `column2` is just the string value of the property you want, treat `data` like an associative array in this case to get the property you're trying to display.

Comment: This will do it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

`column2` was created by the `ng-repeat` and is what you want. Note `{{column2}}`:

```
<td ng-repeat="column2 in tableHeader">{{column2}}</td>
```

Comment: would output all the headings, not what OP is expecting. Note the nested ng-repeat of `td` inside repeating `tr`